# How to get classification report from a single input value

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

I use NLP to classify my data, i have trained my data and now i want to know the score of a single input value. My data contains clothes and fashion stuff, and it should return a category where it belongs. I want to check the classification score from a single input value. 
So i do it like this:

```
bow4 = bow_transformer.transform([message4])
tfidf4 = tfidf_transformer.transform(bow4)
predicted =  spam_detect_model.predict(tfidf4)
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print (classification_report(data['Category Path'], predicted))
```

Then i recieve the following error

**"Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples:"**

Thats because the array size of the predicted value doesnt match the data.

How can i see the classification report from a single predicted value? I want to do this because i want to create some web app where an user can do input. If the classfication score is lower then x for example then it gives an error.

Thanks!

My code in total looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
import string
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
#open file
data = pd.read_csv('cats.csv',sep=';')
data['length'] = data['Product Name'].str.len()
#remove all puncs
def text_process(mess):
    # Check characters to see if they are in punctuation
    nopunc = [char for char in mess if char not in string.punctuation]
    # Join the characters again to form the string.
    nopunc = ''.join(nopunc)
    # Now just remove any stopwords
    return [word for word in nopunc.split() if word.lower() not in stopwords.words('english') if word.lower() not in stopwords.words('dutch')]
# Might take awhile...
bow_transformer = CountVectorizer(analyzer=text_process).fit(data['Product Name'])
# Print total number of vocab words
print(len(bow_transformer.vocabulary_))
messages_bow = bow_transformer.transform(data['Product Name'])


tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer().fit(messages_bow)
messages_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(messages_bow)
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
spam_detect_model = MultinomialNB().fit(messages_tfidf, data['Category Path'])


message4 = "some dummy data "
bow4 = bow_transformer.transform([message4])
tfidf4 = tfidf_transformer.transform(bow4)
predicted =  spam_detect_model.predict(tfidf4)

#errors here
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print (classification_report(data['Category Path'], predicted))
```

Comment: Could you please include your imports and the model instantiation. This way we can see further to it to provide a more directed answer.

Comment: Hi, i modified my question a bit,

Comment: Nice! I know this is not your problem, as I'm still reading through the code. But I noticed that you are joining the words but did not provide a space char to join them. Is that right?

Comment: yeah thats right!

Comment: have you tried printing tfidf4 and checking its lenght?

Comment: No, that will not give me an indication whats the score of the given input

Comment: Have you considered the fact that your network was trained to distinguish about what is a boot, a dress, a hat and a bag, but not what is NOT a dress or hat or bag... That is probably a good reason why you're getting these problems.

Comment: My input is n, so unknown, a user can input anything. ..Is there no way to get a score how good the unknown input n matches against my dataset fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer after trial and error.

So basicly you have a `spam_detect_model.classes_`attribute where you can see the classes.
With `predict_proba` you can find the probability. So now you have to attach them together, so you can do that with the `zip`method in Python.

So for other people struggeling out there, it looks liks this:

````
bow4 = bow_transformer.transform([message4])
tfidf4 = tfidf_transformer.transform(bow4)
counter = 0
predicted = spam_detect_model.predict_proba(tfidf4)
for x in spam_detect_model.classes_: #classes_ gives you the labels,
  proba  = round(predicted[0][counter],2)
  if proba > 0.01: #only return the labels with a prob of larger then 0,10%
      print(x + ' probility '+ str(proba))
  counter +=1 ```
````

Answer (score 0):

classification report purpose is to print precision, recall and F1 score. You can not compute those metric using only one value.

just use the value from `predicted`

Comment: No, that give me not the desires result. If my dataset contains things about fashion, and i enter as input Car , the predicted value contains a category. But the problem is , is that the category is a false negative. Somehow i need the correctness of the given input

Comment: i'm not sure to understand. You want to predict the category of `message4`. You can do it using ur code with the value of `predicted`. You want to compared predicted class with the true category of the sentance? U have to get it from you'r database or to create a variable `message4_true_class = "T-shirt"` for example. Then just do something like `message4_true_class ==predicted`

Comment: I want to predict the category from message4. But the input is unknown. An user can input anything. My dataset is trained for fashion. But if an user input television, or another input unknown to fashion, the it will get a category. So e.g. television gives the category "underwear". My values are not in a database. So what i can read its not possible to match a unknown value n, against my dataset fashion, that will gives me a a score how the unknown input is?

Answer (score -1):

For Multinomial Naive Bayes, you can use predict_proba() function to get a score of each input.